# 'Service does not respond in a timely fashion' error when restarting Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I try to restart my SQL server, I get the following error:

[image]
[image]

Why this error happens and how to solve this?

Comment: Did you check the eventlogs?

Comment: upvotes are gained easily today

Comment: @rene, whatever do you mean? This looks like a really awesome programming question to me.

Comment: @bzlm Awesome it is then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Windows GUI starts a service, it displays a progress box for 60 seconds.  After that, it will display the error "Service failed to resond in a timely fashion".

The message means no more than that the service didn't start in 60 seconds.  This is not necessarily a problem: especially after a system halt, SQL Server can take a long time to start up, as it is rolling transactions backward and forward to get the databases in a consistent state.

Ignore the GUI error message, and check for details in the SQL Server error log.

Comment: If the service doesn't actually start, there won't be anything in the SQL Server error log.

Comment: @bzlm: Well if the excetable cannot be started at all, you'd get a different error message.